# Can a Beast Master upgrade their companion with new powers or choose new forms for them at higher levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

I am brand spanking new to D&D. I heard I picked a class that every experienced player is disappointed with.

I picked a Panther as my pet. I see a lot of lists with the original pets you can choose from, but I can't seem to find a list of pet upgrades (stronger pets at higher levels). My Panther is pretty good right now while I'm only Level 4, but she took ONE hit and almost died twice. So I have to be very careful with her. This seems like a really big issue and I am looking to see if there are options in the book to fix this. I haven't found any yet, but I might be missing them (as I said I'm new).

**So, can a Beast Master upgrade their companion with new powers or choose new forms for them at higher levels?**

Example: At Level 3, I get a Panther. At Level 20, I get a Super Mega All Star Fire Breathing Panther (not necessarily leveling up the Panther to Level 20. Accessing a stronger Challenge Rating). I don't know all of the Challenge Ratings, but I assume 1/4 is not very strong. So my confusion is: I got a 1/4 Challenge rating pet at Level 3. It does seem a little strange that I will have a weak pet at Level 3 and Level 20

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. Can you tell us which edition of D&D you're playing?

Comment: Don't be offended by the votes to close this question. Our experience has taught us we need to know exactly which version of D&D you are playing in order to answer it, once you add it in to either the tags (preferred), body, or comments, we can open it again.

Comment: I think I did that right. I'm playing the new one: dnd5e?

Comment: @PixiiBomb that's the one! And you did is correctly indeed. Your question will be reopened shortly.

Comment: @goodguy5 - not exactly what I was looking for, but good to know. The question is: do I get a pet UPGRADE? Like, we choose a 1/4 Challenge pet at Level 3. Do I choose a higher Challenge rating at a higher level? Or will I ALWAYS have a 1/4 pet?

Comment: @PixiiBomb what makes you think that you would? Is there an aspect of the rules that are unclear?

Comment: @goodguy5 - yea the whole everything is unclear. I've been playing this game for like 5 sessions lol. And most of it is the DM's fiance yelling "I roll to seduce"

Comment: @NautArch - No, as stated - it doesn't answer my question. But his remaining responses are leaning towards "why in the world would you have a pet upgrade anyway?" So I guess it's sort of answering my question.

I just don't understand why I would be Level 3 with a weak pet, and be Level 20 with a weak pet.

Comment: Wait a minute, has the DM (or anyone) given you access to the rulebook where this class is found? If you haven't gotten a chance to read over the class and subclass, that would explain your confusion

Comment: @goodguy5 - we got access to the books on Sunday (2 days ago). So I've been trying to read as much info as I can, and found this website to help answer some of my questions. We've all (including the DM) just been winging it since we started. None of us know what we're doing

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what *isn't* answered in the duplicate question. You seem to be asking if it levels up/improves as you level up and that's exactly what's asked in that one. Is there something I' missing or are you really asking "this doesn't seem right, why is this?"

Comment: @PixiiBomb I think you have stumbled on one of the most criticized aspects of the class. The creature is pretty weak and frail for the entire time the character owns them. As pointed out in the other answer, they do get more powerful a bit as you go on, but there is no other way they increase in power.

Comment: @NautArch - maybe a little of both.
The original question was about pet upgrades (for lack of a better term), not level up the pet.
Example: At Level 3, I get a Panther. At Level 20, I get a Super Mega All Star Fire Breathing Panther (not necessarily leveling up the Panther to Level 20. Accessing a stronger Challenge Rating). I don't know all of the Challenge Ratings, but I assume 1/4 is not very strong.

So my confusion is: I got a 1/4 Challenge rating pet at Level 3. It does seem a little strange that I will have a weak pet at Level 3 and Level 20.

Comment: Related:  [What is the evidence, if any, that the Ranger Beast Master archetype is comparatively underpowered?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140937) and [Can a Beast Master ranger armor their animal companion with barding?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53627)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose - thanks for the insight. I think I'm just going to try and find some youtube videos, (and read those posts) that might help me find a way to play the class where I don't feel so useless >.<

Comment: @PixiiBomb You can actually ask that here. What you are experiencing is called an XY problem here. Your real problem is that your pet is weak. So you asked about what you thought might be the solution: missing pet upgrades. However asking directly about the issue is usually the best strategy. So, you should ask a  new question about how to increase the survivability of your pet and then we can probably help you out. There's no penalty for asking multiple questions so feel free to do so at any time.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose - thanks I will keep that in mind. I will probably have a million more questions, the more I read the books. It's funny because people are like "how is that not clear?" And I'm like "well... you know... when my husband talks about cars, I have no idea what he's talking about. And when I talk to him about programming, he has no idea what I'm talking about." We all didn't come out of our mother's womb with D&D knowledge. I will understand everything eventually - but right now, I'm a little lost. So I appreciate the /assist :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90943/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-pixii-bomb).